# How can I record a video with sound of my app using Android Studio?

Tags: android, video-capture, audio-recording

I am developing an app with Android Studio 2.1 and I would like to record a video of an usage example, with sound.

I have already recorded some videos, but always without sound. As the sound in my app is a key feature, I would like to have the video with the audio output of my app.

Is it possible? In case it is, how could I use it?

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried running my app, and then at the _Android Monitor_ (alt+6), using Screen Record. I have also searched in google and here, but most of the results where solutions for recording sound in android, such as [this guide in Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) that doesn't help me with my issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using external app for recording both screen and sound. I have dig in just few mins and i have found some apps.

Here I left link to a top http://www.androidauthority.com/best-screen-recording-apps-600838/

The last one seems to be the one you are looking for (SCR Screen Recorder, which requires root), hope it works!

Other option could be to use a male to male audio cable and record the audio transmitted to the pc.